# Google AdMob not working on my flash as3 app

Tags: android, actionscript-3, flash, admob

I'm having a problem. So I'm using codealchemy's ANE and XML to do this. I implemted he ANE and modified the XML so it would work and it did. But the problem is my AS3 is not working, I'm having no errors popping up at all but it's just when I open the App on the google play store(this app is only for android devices) then the ads don't pop up. Can someone please help? Here is my AS3 code: http://pastebin.com/phf9SYid
And here is codealchemy's page from where I followed his tutorial: https://github.com/lancelot1/ane-admob

My app is called "The FRunner" it's only on the google play store. Thank you.

(EDIT) It's still not fixed but the if(adMobManager.isSupported){ } function says it's not supported because I made an else with that if() just now and it replies with not supported. Does anyone know why it says that? I put my ANE correctly and I should have put my XML correctly?

Comment: I'm not sure, but I think that you should either call `showBanner` function or set `mAutoShow` as `true`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I did not use codealchemy's ANE,and I am use http://code.google.com/p/flash-air-admob-ane-for-ios-and-android   so I do not very sure is there any error in your code.

but if isSupported say false,then it maybey you not pack the apk right.
make sure you have packed the ane

(right click your flash builder project and then choose  project properties-->package properties-->android option-->native extension , check the ane lib up)